# Create a sqllte file with password

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite, ios7

I use a x-code 5 to write an application to iPhone 4s with objective-C.

How can i create a data base file (*.sqlite) with password.
every read or write a password need to be enter.

Comment: Use an implementation of SqlCipher.  It's not provided by Apple and I'm not sure there are any free pre-built versions available, so you either have to pay for a version or port it yourself (which is certainly feasible but non-trivial).

Comment: (I don't think the "duplicate" is, though there probably are other more appropriate duplicates that could be referenced.)

Comment: [This page](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial) appears to tell you how to build SqlCipher for iOS.  I've not reviewed it, though.  (I actually couldn't find any reasonable "duplicates" in a brief search.)

Comment: Hi i not received a correct answer.
I need that the created data base file will be with password (db.sqlite) . today i use sqlite3.

Comment: If you want a password-protected file you must use SqlCiper or some other such package.  Yes, you can use Apple's built-in file encryption, but with that you have to decrypt the entire file when the app starts, then re-encrypt when the app ends -- neither convenient nor secure.